# How to hide pay with card option in pay pal payment method

Tags: ios, swift, paypal-sandbox

I'm using **Paypal payment gateway** for my project. So I'm using Paypal lib into my project. In that, I don't need *pay with card* option. I need to ***hide this pay with card button***. (Refer below Screenshot)

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If u link Card.io Framework to your app,then the option come. 
U don't want CardPayment option,

```
   PayPalConfiguration *PayPal_Configure = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
   PayPal_Configure.acceptCreditCards = NO;
```

Comment: U link libCardIO this library means, remove that. its working for me.

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: U link any framework libCardIO library from CardiO. Remove that library, then do above process. Bcuz here its working fine. i checked now also.